# How to make background image to looks proportional?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have login page with background image, problem is cus image does not looks as original photo:

Check the screenshot - width of image is problem:
[image]

This is HTML/jsx of page:

```
 <div className="login-page">

   <picture>

     <source srcSet={mobileImg} media="(min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px)" />

     <source srcSet={tabletImg} media="(min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 900px)" />

     <img srcSet={desktopImg} className="login-background" alt="background image" />

   </picture>

   <div className="login-wrapper">{children}</div>

 </div>
```

This is css part:

```
.login-page {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
}

.login-wrapper {
    align-self: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.login-background {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

How to make image responsive?

Comment: What's the problem with how the picture is presented in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image shown by `<img>` tags are not handled by `background-*` css attributes. You could use `object-fit: cover` instead

Comment: @MarkJames this is not supported in IE11. [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is that the image is presented without preserving the aspect ratio. Background properties won't work for `img` tags. So below code will not work for you.

```
/* Will not work for img */
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Use below code which is similar to the background properties you have used.

```
img {
  object-fit: none;
  object-position: 50% 50%; 
  /* OR */
  object-position: center;
}
```

For more refer this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/